# pandas - pivot_table while preserving order fails

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame where week are not ISO weeks but fiscal weeks (1 is 1st week of July, 52 is last week of June):

```
> df
     domain  week  count
0        A    43      5
1        A    45      1
2        A    50      1
3        A    51      4
4        A     1      3
5        A     3     12
6        B    43      1
7        B    44      1
8        B    45      4
9        B    50     11
10       B     2      3
11       B     3     12
12       C    51      6
13       C     1     14
14       C     5      1
```

I want to pivot this table while preserving the order of the week to get a new data frame that would look like the following with the values being count and the columns being the domain:

```
> new_df
week   A      B     C
43      5     1   NaN
44    NaN     1   NaN
45      1     4   NaN      
50      1    11   NaN
51      4   NaN     6
1       3   NaN    14
2     NaN     3   NaN
3      12    12   NaN
5     NaN   NaN     1
```

I tried using groupie and unstuck but got this error:

```
> df = df.groupby(['week'], sort=False)['count'].unstack('domain')
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'unstack' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1]** You can use custom ordered `weeks` index helper and `.loc`

```
In [4810]: weeks = pd.Index(list(range(26, 52)) + list(range(26)))

In [4819]: dfp = df.groupby(['week','domain'])['count'].sum().unstack()

In [4820]: dfp.loc[weeks & dfp.index]
Out[4820]:
domain     A     B     C
43       5.0   1.0   NaN
44       NaN   1.0   NaN
45       1.0   4.0   NaN
50       1.0  11.0   NaN
51       4.0   NaN   6.0
1        3.0   NaN  14.0
2        NaN   3.0   NaN
3       12.0  12.0   NaN
5        NaN   NaN   1.0
```

**Option 2]** Or, use `pivot`

```
In [4821]: dfp = df.pivot('week', 'domain', 'count')

In [4822]: dfp.loc[weeks & dfp.index]
Out[4822]:
domain     A     B     C
43       5.0   1.0   NaN
44       NaN   1.0   NaN
45       1.0   4.0   NaN
50       1.0  11.0   NaN
51       4.0   NaN   6.0
1        3.0   NaN  14.0
2        NaN   3.0   NaN
3       12.0  12.0   NaN
5        NaN   NaN   1.0
```

**Option 3]** Or, `reindex` instead of `.loc`

```
In [4830]: dfp.reindex(weeks & dfp.index)
Out[4830]:
domain     A     B     C
43       5.0   1.0   NaN
44       NaN   1.0   NaN
45       1.0   4.0   NaN
50       1.0  11.0   NaN
51       4.0   NaN   6.0
1        3.0   NaN  14.0
2        NaN   3.0   NaN
3       12.0  12.0   NaN
5        NaN   NaN   1.0
```

---

Details

```
In [4826]: weeks
Out[4826]:
Int64Index([26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
            43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
             8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
            25],
           dtype='int64')

In [4827]: weeks & dfp.index
Out[4827]: Int64Index([43, 44, 45, 50, 51, 1, 2, 3, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom order of `week`s, so need [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation) with custom order and omit `sort=False`:

```
cats = list(range(26, 52)) + list(range(26))
print (cats)
[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

df['week'] = df['week'].astype('category', ordered=True, categories=cats)

df = df.groupby(['week','domain'])['count'].sum().unstack()
print (df)
domain     A     B     C
week                    
43       5.0   1.0   NaN
44       NaN   1.0   NaN
45       1.0   4.0   NaN
50       1.0  11.0   NaN
51       4.0   NaN   6.0
1        3.0   NaN  14.0
2        NaN   3.0   NaN
3       12.0  12.0   NaN
5        NaN   NaN   1.0
```

Comment: The problem is that week 44 and week 2 are misplaced. Week 44 should come between 43 and 45, and week 2 should come between 1 and 3.

Comment: Hmm, so ordering is [26,27...,51,0,1,..,25] ?